# Broke(?) my USB flash drive while burning a Windows 10 ISO from Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, gparted

I have a working Linux distribution running (Arch Linux) on my computer, I followed tutorials on burning an ISO of Windows 10 on my USB drive.

Came across this answer on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/840797/559712

I followed it, got stuck at the `sudo ms-sys -7 /dev/sdc` part. It just didn't do anything, got stuck. I tried to unmount the partition, it said that the device is busy. So I rebooted my computer.

Now, when I open GParted, I get the following error message: `Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb`. I click 'ignore' multiple times so the error goes away.

Once GParted starts, I switch to the USB device and see 7.9GB being unallocated.
This is what I see in the 'disks' gnome application: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Um9p.png)

So in GParted, I press the button to make a new partition table, as `msdos` of course for the Windows 10 installation USB I want to create. When I press 'apply', GParted freezes and this happens:

> “/dev/sdb - GParted” is not responding.
>
> You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the
>   application to quit entirely.

So - did I break my USB flash drive? How could I possibly make it work again? What am I supposed to do to burn a Windows 10 ISO on it..?

I can probably get Windows 10 burned on it with Rufus on my sister's computer, but getting the USB flash drive to work first is the important part of course!

Comment: (1) Make sure you are using the correct device (was it `/dev/sdc` or /dev/sdb`?) Use `lsscsi` to see which device is which. (2) Did you use the USB stick to full capacity before? There are "fake" USB sticks from China which report a higher capacity than they actually have, and could hang when trying to use it.